# Can the VGA cable screw the videocard?

Tags: windows-10, resolution, display-driver

I bought a second-hand desktop, Dell Optiplex 990 SFF, Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz, 16 Gb DDR3, Windows10. The monitor has a resolution of 1980x1020. In the second day I changed the VGA cable with a longer one, while the computer was on, and since then the resolution stuck at 1366x768 and the refresh rate at 59,750 Hz. I can't change it from Display setting or Advanced display settings. From Device Manager, for Display Adapter - Intel(R) HD Graphics, I tried the options: "rollback driver", "update driver", and finally "uninstall device". Nothing helped, the resolution is still stuck at 1366x768. Please, help me to fix it. What else I can do to fix this problem?

Comment: Do not use VGA anymore if at all possible, especially not for resolutions that high. // Did you try changing back the cable?

Comment: VGA is not hot-swappable. You may have damaged something on the GPU.

Comment: @Tetsujin In practice, it absolutely is. It was regularly used this way with laptops and projectors in office environments.

Comment: I find it dubious to say that "hot swapping" a VGA cable could cause problems since the cable only has analog signals. The fact the port is functional, and the display is working indicates no damage has been done. I have "hot swapped" VGA cables for nearly 2 decades without any issues, I might have had to restart the system, but that(s) a different topic.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with older Intel HD graphics.
They can be really finicky with VGA cables and monitors.
(And in some cases that odd-ball refresh rate, just under 60 Hz, is something the monitor can't handle.)

You just have to experiment with several cables until you find one that works as desired.

Even better: If your monitor has a digital input use the DisplayPort output of the computer in stead. That won't have this issue and the image equality will be much better too.

Comment: Also, its not written explicitly in the answer, but sometimes a monitor set to a different refreshrate than 60hz may not allow you to change the resolution, but if you first set it to 60hz, then suddenly you can change it again.

Comment: @LPChip You are right about that. I had totally forgotten about that oddity.